# Can I put an AMD APU and an Nvidia GPU in the same computer

Tags: cpu, gpu

As the title says, can I put an AMD APU Procesor and an Nvidia GPU in the same PC?

These kinda bugs me because the APU I’ll be buying has the power of an AMD R9 240 I think. And I know that Nvidia and AMD GPU’s can’t mix, so it’s a bit complicated for me.

Comment: Of course you can.  You can't install two display drivers, so only one GPU, will actually be used by software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting since [Windows 7 (WDDM 1.1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model#WDDM_1.1) you can installs 2 different GPU drivers and use a nVIDIA GPU side by side to an AMD APU.